# How to fix 'Zlib Exception: Bad state (incorrect data check)'

Tags: c#, exception, zlib

I'm working with files which constanins a hundreds of fragments of compressed data. I'm using Threadpool for this. Every fragment of data is given to Threadpool queue.

RawData is an array of bytes and exception is on 181 line, which is

```
decompress.CopyTo(mem);
```

All what I noticed is that if I just run application then there will generate dozens of ZlibExceptions. If I would debug it and application sometimes is in idle state then there is a few excetions. After that I put a sleep method for 1 second between decompressing data and I got 4 exceptions only.

RawData is an array of bytes.

```
ZlibStream decompress = new ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(c.RawData), CompressionMode.Decompress);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
decompress.CopyTo(mem);
```

```
Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException: Bad state (incorrect data check)
   w Ionic.Zlib.InflateManager.Inflate(FlushType flush)
   w Ionic.Zlib.ZlibCodec.Inflate(FlushType flush)
   w Ionic.Zlib.ZlibBaseStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   w Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   w System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   w System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
   w myApp.Form1.Decompress(Object state) w X:\Path\To\Projects\myApp\myApp\Form1.cs:wiersz 181
```

I'm using Threadpool, so delaying workers is pointless. I can't find any solutions of that random exception which depends on how fast application executes.

Comment: By default, types are not thread-safe unless the author takes great care to make them thread-safe, so the obvious question would be if you're sharing objects across threads in any way, shape or form. Sharing an array is safe (if not modified) but just about anything else is not. In particular, `Stream` and its descendants are not thread-safe, as they implicitly contain the concept of a current position.

Comment: Note also that `MemoryStream` merely wraps around an existing array; it does not copy one. If `c.RawData` is changed after being handed off to this code, the results will be unpredictable.

Comment: I'm creating a new object (c) for every thread.

Comment: Okey I figure it out now. Changed ZlibStream to ZlibCodec with some properties about Inflate and Flush. Thanks for advice.